# Smarter algorithmic way to accomplish recursive search function in R?

Tags: r

I know this is more algorithmic than R-related, but I'm wondering if the solution exists within any R packages that exist. This code example identifies the first manager of an employee that is a VP. Is there a faster way to conduct this on a large set of data? It seems like it's a depth first search. Could this be accomplished using `graph.dfs`?

```
x <- data.frame(employee=c('xy', 'abc', 'zz', 'xx', 'yy', 'ww'), manager=c('abc', 'zz', 'xx', 'yy', 'ww', 'uu'), level=c('dir', 'man', 'vp', 'vp', 'man', 'vp'))
emps <- as.character(unique(x$employee))
x$employee<-as.character(x$employee)
x$manager<-as.character(x$manager)

findVP <- function(emp){
    employee <- x[which(x$employee == emp),]
    if(employee$level == 'vp'){
        return (emp)
    } else{
        findVP(x[which(x$employee == emp),]$manager)
    }
}


sapply(emps, findVP)
```

Expected output (if an employee IS a VP, should return himself):

```
emp  first_VP_manager
"xy" "zz"
"abc" "zz"
"zz" "zz"
"xx" "xx"
"yy" "ww"
"ww" "ww"
```

Comment: most likely `ifelse(x$level == "vp", x$employee, x$manager)`. Post the expected output to be sure.

Comment: Confusing that you call this "findManager" and yet clearly mean "findVP" or "find_department_VP". You have a manager column, but this does not correspond to it.

Comment: The corporate graph here is pretty crazy. `zz` is a VP, but is below another VP, `yy`, who is another several rungs below VP `uu`.

Comment: @Frank agreed, I updated the function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no pro at `igraph`, but messing around with it a bit, you could do something like the following if you want to use a graph data structure.

```
## Setup an edgelist
vps <- x[x$level=='vp', 'employee']
mat <- rbind(as.matrix(x[!(x$employee %in% vps),2:1]), cbind('vp', vps))

## Make a graph and look at it
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(mat)
plot(g, layout=layout.reingold.tilford(g, root="vp"))
```

[image]

```
## Leaves of graph (thought there would be a function for this?)
leaves <- V(g)[degree(g, mode='out')==0]

## Get the vps for each branch, print result
res <- lapply(all_simple_paths(g, from='vp', to=leaves), function(x) names(x)[-1])

setNames(res, sapply(res, `[`, 1))         
# $zz
# [1] "zz"  "abc" "xy" 
# 
# $ww
# [1] "ww" "yy"
# 
# $xx
# [1] "xx"
```

Comment: This is really cool. So does this just return all of the child nodes of a VP node (including the VP node)?

Comment: take a look at `all_simple_paths(g, from='vp', to=leaves)`.  It returns the paths from `vp` to the leaves (including the dummy `vp` node - hence the `[-1]` later on).  I thought there might be a function to just return all children of a node, but couldn't find one.

Comment: for your expected output, you could use `cbind(rep(sapply(res, \`[\`, 1), lengths(res)), unlist(res))`